# How to set default value in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: json, asp.net-core-webapi

I am learning ASP.NET Core Web API, and it's using the `System.Text.Json` namespace instead of JSON.NET.

How to set the default value for the model binding?

Someone tells me that the `[DefaultValue]` attribute is not working anymore, is that correct?

If so what's the alternative option?

Comment: did you check msdn? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 1):

with latest c# you can do this.

```
public class Student
{
  public string name { get; set; } = "YourDefaultValue"
}
```

then you can use `System.text.json` to serialize. check below example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below is a demo, you can refer to it.

Student

```
public class Student
    {
      public string name { get; set; }    
    }
```

ValuesController

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get(string name="Tom")
        {
            return $"Hello {name}!";
        }
     }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: what you are showing is default value for a parameter not for a property of class. there is not relation between class "student" and "controller" in your example. and then how do you set default value for all the properties of the class.